# Why is my rendered animation showing a hexadecagon border around my image?

Tags: rendering

I am using blender 2.91 for Mac. I am trying to animate an inflating balloon flying away on a still image. When I toggle to camera view everything looks ok, yet when I go to render the animation I get a darker image with a hexadecagon border around the image. I attached two screenshots below to provide further context for my question.
Thank you in advance!

[image: Camera View]

[image: Render View]

Comment: maybe you've given a Subdisivision Surface modifier to your image, check the modifiers panel

Comment: You were right, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plane:

[image]

Here's the same plane with a subsurf modifier:

[image]

Now the object has more vertices instead of the original 4.

The subdivision modifier creates new "virtual" geometry, by interpolating the existing edges and faces.

> The Subdivision Surface modifier (often shorten to “Subdiv”) is used to split the faces of a mesh into smaller faces, giving it a smooth appearance. It enables you to create complex smooth surfaces while modeling simple, low-vertex meshes. It avoids the need to save and maintain huge amounts of data, and gives a smooth “organic” look to the object.

If you use (default) ***Catmul-clark*** subdivision the object will be rounded.

To keep the plane like a parallelogram, use ***Simple*** subdivision:

[image]