# Why are the edges of the corners of some of my objects curving off after I render?

Tags: rendering, edges

So I’m making a low res PS1 style scene, and a couple of the objects in my scene have their edges curve off after I render the scene, such as the checkered floor here -
[image]

However sometimes it fixes itself after I go straight from edit mode of that object to render mode ? This is how it should look -
[image]

Could anyone tell me what’s causing this or how to fix it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier on the checkered floor?

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208406/why-is-my-rendered-animation-showing-a-hexadecagon-border-around-my-image/208458#208458

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with the viewport level set to 0.

[image]

When rendered with the *Catmull-Clark* algorithm this adds extra faces based on the Render setting and interpolates their location.

[image]